# OData V4 Easy way to update Model?

Tags: odata, sapui5, odata-v4

I am creating a To-Do List App in SAPUI5 and have connected my OData V4 Model from a CAP Project.
The issue I have is that I cannot update my Object status to "done" when it is selected.
I looked up several documentations and posts on Stackoverflow, yet I cannot find a easy solution to update a OData V4 Model. Here is my function and a create function as well to add entries to my current list:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyqeH.png)

The error I currently receive is: Uncaught Error: The binding must be deferred: Books(6)
[Update entity data using OData V4 and oListData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76344744/update-entity-data-using-odata-v4-and-olistdata)
The only solution I could think of was deleting and creating an identical model, but I want to refrain from doing this, due to it changing the sequence of my List entries..
Does anybody know an easier way to simply update my Object to change the status to "Done" ?

I  tried  to use this previous stackoverflow answer but it doesnt work
[Update entity data using OData V4 and oListData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76344744/update-entity-data-using-odata-v4-and-olistdata)